# How to replace comma-separated text in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

One of the columns in my dataframe contains a comma-separated text, like "One, two, three":

```
df =
  Col1               Col2
  One, two, three    Abc
  Two                Def
```

I want to replace `One, two, three` by `One_two_three`.

If I apply this code:

```
df['Col1'].replace("One, two, three", "One_two_three",inplace=True)
```

... it does not change anything. Why?

Comment: that should've worked, what does `print(df['Col1'].iloc[0])` output? you may have trailing spaces or other characters, alternatively you could do `df['Col1'].str.replace(', ', '_')`

Comment: @EdChum: It outputs `One, two, three`.

Comment: @EdChum: I tested your proposed solution. It outputs the same result `One, two, three`. Well, to be more specific I indeed have `One, two and three`, but I don't think that it changes anything.

Comment: It looks like you have 2 spaces between `two,` and `three`, try `df['Col1'].replace("One, two,  three", "One_two_three",inplace=True)` or possibly a tab, can you post raw data and code to reproduce your df

Comment: Might there be a space after three? Maybe just strip whitespaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generalized solution that handles blanks and even outer commas if needed:

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x.replace(' ','').split(',')).strip('_'))
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['x, w , wwwa,ds','x,a,a','y,c','y',',z,']})

             Col1
0  x, w , wwwa,ds
1           x,a,a
2             y,c
3               y
4             ,z,
```

Result:

```
          Col1
0  x_w_wwwa_ds
1        x_a_a
2          y_c
3            y
4            z
```

If you have no outer commas, just leave out the last `.strip('_')` part.

Answer (score 1):

apply is not necessarily needed

```
df["Col1"] = df["Col1"].str.replace(' ','').str.replace(',','_').str.strip('_')

          Col1
0  x_w_wwwa_ds
1        x_a_a
2          y_c
3            y
4            z
```

also works. I'm not sure which approach is recommended performance wise